# How to add unity generated (xcode) project to another xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have just created a unity application and exported that to xcode.

How can I add the exported project to another xcode project and add the view created in unity on top of window?

I have added and removed all the compile time errors, but when I run the application and try to load the view created in unity, the application crashes and I receive this error:

> The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded

Any kind of help would be very much appreciated